# Pull Request displays a 'git --diff...' command?

Tags: git, bitbucket, diff, pull-request

I'm facing a strange behavior with Git and BitBucket.
I created a Pull Request in order to merge my branch into the mother branch.
There is no conflict, however at the bottom of some source code files, I can see:

```
      [code]
    }
  }
  diff --git a/src/..[path]../xxx.component.ts b/src/..[path]../xxx.component.ts
```

I don't understand why this command is shown here?...
3 files of my Pull Request have similar line at the bottom, and for one of them, the file xxx doesn't correspond to the merged source code.

Could you please explain me this behavior?
Is that an error? An alert? Anything else?

Thank you for your help
Best regards

Comment: looks like someone typed the git commands on a wrong windows...

Comment: do you see the line in local bash, or in some online code editor?

Comment: No, these lines aren't visible somewhere else, they are not present in real source code...
I can't notice any impact on the application.

Comment: then it maybe some tools' function to tell the git command that generates outputs.

Comment: Ok thank you  Lei, ΦXocę :)